# Interior and closure of $A = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{0\}$

Tags: general-topology

Given $A = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{0\}$ I want to find its interior and closure, where the space is $\mathbb{R}$.

For the interior I've said that since $A \subseteq  \mathbb{Q}$, then $int(A) \subseteq int(\mathbb{Q}) = \emptyset$. I hope it's right.

Now for the closure my intuition tells me that $cl(A) = A$, but I don't know how to prove $cl(A) \subseteq A$.

Comment: In what space? With what topology? Considering closures and interiors is always relative to some space. For example $int(A)=cl(A)=A$ in $A$.

Comment: If you are working in $\mathbb{R}$, would you know how to prove that $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you know that a set's interior is the union of all open sets it contains and its closure is the intersection of all closed sets containing it.

Your reasoning with respect to the interior is correct.  If $U \subseteq A$ is open, then since $A \subseteq \Bbb Q$, we have $U \subseteq \Bbb Q$.  But we already know that $\Bbb Q$ has empty interior, so it contains no non-empty open sets.  Therefore, $U = \varnothing$, meaning the only open set contained in $A$ is the empty set, so $A$ has empty interior.

You can easily prove, if you haven't already, that any closed set is its own closure, so to get the result you're looking for (which is correct), you can prove that $A$ is closed.  One way to do that is to prove that its complement is open.  If $r \notin A$ and $r \lt 0$, then an open ball with radius $\frac {\vert r \vert}{2}$ is completely contained in $\Bbb R \setminus A$.

You don't have to worry about $r=0$ because if that's the case, $r \in A$.

If $r \notin A$ and $r \gt 0$, it's easy to prove either that $1 \lt r$ (in which case the proof is quite easy) or for some $n, \frac{1}{n+1} \lt r \lt \frac 1n$.  With the latter inequality, let $\varepsilon= \dfrac {\min(r-\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac 1n - r)}{2}$.  Again, you'll have an open set containing $r$ completely contained in $\Bbb R \setminus A$.  Combining these results shows that $\Bbb R \setminus A$ is open, so $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

A point $x\in A$ is an interior point if there is an $\epsilon>0$ and an $\epsilon$-nbd $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ of $x$ contained in $A$. It is obvious that no point of $A$ has such a nbd, that is, no point of $A$ is an interior point. So, the interior of $A$ is empty set: $A^{\circ}=\emptyset$.

A point $x\in \Bbb R$ is a closure point of $A$ if any open nbd of $x$ intersects $A$. It is clear that $A\subset\bar{A}$. We can show that if $x\not\in A$, then $x$ is not a closure point: $1)$ If $x>1$, then $(\frac{x+1}{2},2x)\cap A=\emptyset$ $2)$ If $\frac1n< x<\frac{1}{n-1}$, then $(\frac{nx+1}{2n},\frac{nx+1-x}{2n-2})\cap A=\emptyset$ $3)$ If $x<0$, then $(2x,\frac x2)\cap A=\emptyset$. So, the closure of $A$ is itself: $\bar{A}=A$. It is a closed set.